# Expected underlying daily move from implied volatility

Tags: options, implied-volatility

Suppose I have 3 ATM call options on an underlying with time to maturity 1, 2, and 3 months, respectively, priced at implied volatility level $\sigma_1$, $\sigma_2$, $\sigma_3$. Given that there will be a major macro event after 1 month but within 2 months in the future, how can i use these info to compute the expected daily move of the underlying for the macro event day?

I know we can compute expected daily move for earning event by using ATM straddle covering the event day and look at breakeven points. But given that we only have call options here, I'm guess could constructing a calendar spread help?

Comment: I don't think you can really. Many people do use that logic (that the straddle represents the mean absolute deviation of the stock price). However, option pricing is done in a risk neutral world.  Therefore, any probabilistic statements derived from options are only valid in the risk-neutral world and have little to do with actual real world probabilities.

Comment: It is quite difficult, I don't believe there is an exact way of doing this. Sometimes you need to get creative... one thing you can try is to try and predict $\sigma_2$ from $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_3$. Then compare the difference between the predicted value, and the actual value. One might argue that is the extra risk premium. From there, you can estimate a daily expected move. 

Then again, there are a lot of dangerous assumptions that needs to be made, and we don't know the accuracy.